# Boundary Norm skips a color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph where each node has two features that are categorical with scores from 1 to 5 (inclusive) and wanted to display them with different colors depending on the difference. For that I made a range of 9 colors so it's easy to visualize and tried using matplotlibs ListedColormap and Boundary norm, but it is not working as it assigns 3 and 4 the same color.

Here is a code to display the difference.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Define the colors to be used
colors = ['#5328D4', '#8772EA', '#988BF4', '#D9D6FB', '#303030', '#F9E2CF', '#F6C69F', '#F2AB71', '#ED762F']

# Define the colormap
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(name='Neutral color difference (no white)', colors=colors)

# Define the bounds and the norm
bounds = np.arange(-4,5)
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, ncolors=len(bounds), clip=True)

# Print the bounds and the color assigned to each bound by the norm
print(f'Bounds: {bounds}\nColors: {norm(bounds)}')

# Plot the scale so its easier to see using a linspace to check for possible precision errors
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-4,5,90)
ax.scatter(x, np.zeros(len(x)), c=x, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
for bound in bounds:
    ax.axvline(bound, ls=':', c='lightgray')
plt.show()
```

This results in:

```
Bounds: [-4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4]
Colors: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 8]
```

[image]

Which showcases that 3 and 4 are assigned the same color and that the seventh color is not used.

I've tried adding bounds and the problem is solved if I define bounds to be a range from -4 to 7 but I don't understand why this is happening and I'm afraid there might be bugs on different parts of the code. Does anyone know what I am missing?
Thank you in advance

Comment: If you have 9 boundaries, you only delimit 8 regions.  You could try `bounds = np.arange(-4.5, 5)` to have nice bounds in between the integer values (`-4.5, -3.5, ...., 3.5, 4.5`).